# Matrix $3$-norm

Tags: matrices, optimization, normed-spaces, matrix-norms

> The $3$-norm on $\mathbb R^n$ is defined as
>
> $$\|x\|_3 := \sqrt[3]{|x_1|^3+\dots+|x_n|^3}$$
>
> The natural matrix norm it induces on $\mathbb R^{n \times n}$ is
>
> $$\|A\|_3 = \max_{\|x\|_3=1} \|Ax\|_3$$
>
> For $y \in \mathbb R$, let
>
> $$A_y = \left(\begin{matrix} 1 & y \\ 0 & 1 \end{matrix}\right)$$
>
> Give a table showing $\|A_y\|_3$ for $y = 1, \dots, 9$.

Comment: Since it's about numerical method, you have to write a program. What have you done?

Comment: Working with Maple, writing a script.  In the last 2 days, i have tried several things.  But i cannot find much information on the 3 norm.  the 1 2 and infinity are simple.  Honestly, i have nothing done and i have no idea where to start. Virtually given up.

Comment: It's an optimization problem with constraints... Hint: You can replace the constraint $\|x\|_3=1$ by $\|x\|_3\leq 1$ which makes it a convex constraint...

Answer (score 3):

Well, I've gone through it. I would say the reason this is given to you in $\mathbb R^2$ is for you to see some actual pictures. First, I like $x,y$ for the coordinates, let us call the matrix $A_w$ for $w = 1, 2, \ldots,9.$ The "superellipse" given by $$ |x|^3 + |y|^3 = 1,  $$ appearance discussed [HERE](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Superellipse), 
 can be parametrized in the first quadrant by $$ x = (\cos t)^{2/3},  \; \;  y = (\sin t)^{2/3},  \; \; 0 \leq t \leq \pi/2.   $$ In the second quadrant,   $$ x = - |\cos t|^{2/3},  \; \;  y = (\sin t)^{2/3},  \; \; \pi / 2 \leq t \leq \pi.   $$ If you have (or write) a function that is traditionally called "signum," where signum of a real number is $1$ if the number is positive, $-1$ if the number is negative, and $0$ if the number is itself $0,$ you can write the parametrization for the entire superellipse. Anyway, the matrix $A_w$ takes such a column vector with entries $x,y$ to $(x+wy,y).$ You can simply have the computer tell you the value of the 3-norm at these points $(x+wy,y)$ for a fairly fine division of $t.$ Once you have the values of $t$ where the 3-norm is largest, restrict to that region and subdivide the $t$ values 10 times smaller. The "sheared" superellipse is $$ x = (\cos t)^{2/3} + w (\sin t)^{2/3},  \; \;  y = (\sin t)^{2/3},  \; \; 0 \leq t \leq \pi/2.   $$ The linear transformation you were given is called a "shear" from physics traditions.

Meanwhile, it is of course true that this can be done with Lagrange multipliers, but the calculation is not elegant and I do not think that is what the instructor wants. Program this, output some pictures, keep subdividing $t$ to get better accuracy, learn something gritty and hands-on.

Answer (score 0):

We have
$$A_y x = \begin{pmatrix} x_1 + y x_2 \\ x_2 \end{pmatrix} .$$
You want to maximize
$$(x_1 + yx_2)^3 + x_2^3$$
with the constraint
$$x_1^3 + x_2^3 = 1.$$
In other words, you want to find the saddle point of the Lagrangian
$$L(x,\lambda) = (x_1 + yx_2)^3 + x_2^3 + \lambda (x_1^3 + x_2^3 - 1).$$
This is very simple to do in any CAS or even by hand.

Comment: Didn't you forget to take the absolute values before cubing?